# Need help understanding certain block of code in python used for a challange assignment

Tags: python

```
factors = [(3, 'Pling'), (5, 'Plang'), (7, 'Plong')]


def convert(number):
    result = ''.join(
        [value for key, value in factors if number % key == 0])
    return str(result or number)
```

How does this code block behave when I run the function? I was doing a coding challenge and completed it using if statements but I didn't feel like it was satisfying enough and started to think of another way to solve the problem that can be way more expandable.

I thought about having a dictionary and using the keys and values in a smart way to make it so I only needed to change the "factors" variable and nothing else. I tried some solutions but it just didn't feel efficient enough.

I then decided to see if anyone else had a similar thought and I found the solution above but I don't understand it entirely. How does this code block actually work?

Let's say I choose the number 21. What is happening in between the brackets? How does this line seem to iterate every tuple, get the value and key, compare the key to my chosen number and then put a value in the list depending on the result of the comparison in such a compact way?

Comment: What part(s) of it *do* you understand?

Comment: I understand that the function iterates over every tuple in factors and that it adds an element into a list if the if statement returns true. The brackets have to do with the fact that a list is produced but why is the comma there and how does the if statement work. `value in factors` returns a boolean from what I know but I'm not sure how it fits in with the other code.

Also... Is there another forum where I should post these kinds of questions? The downvotes seem to suggest so.

Comment: The comma is called "unpacking". You can loop over multidimensional objects easier with it. The square brackets actually aren't needed, and make the code slower as a result of them being there. It's a "generator statement". To avoid downvotes, show the research you've done or how you think the code works. We don't need to know where you got it

Answer (score 0):

factors is a list of tuples

The rest of it can be re-written like so for those that don't understand list comprehension / truthiness

```
def convert(number):
    result = ''
    for key, value in factors: 
        if number % key == 0:
            result += value
    return str(result or number)
```

For the return, if no modulo == 0, then the string is empty, and the number input is returned. [From the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> Note that neither and nor or restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value

Note: You have not shown what values that `number` is, so its hard to explain what the code attempts to do

Comment: You confirmed how I thought the return statement behaves so thanks for clarifying. The thing I'm looking for is understanding the syntax in a more general sense so that I know I can use it well in the future if I ever find a reason to. What is happening in between the brackets? Lets say I choose the numbe 21. How does this line seem to iterate every tuple, get the value and key, compare these values to other values and then put an element in the list depending on the result of the comparison in such a compact way? I guess that's the real question I'm looking for.

Comment: Search "list comprehension". Go through the official Python tutorials on their website